# Copy datetime to same table after conversion

Tags: mysql, sql-server, datetime

Very new to SQL 2 weeks in. I have date in table have added extra columns in table, copied  date field to each column. Alter the dates for 6 &18 weeks from original date. I need to convert the date to uk short date & copy  result to table preferably replacing existing data in the columns.

```
COLUMNS are  REF_DATE this is original date
Six_wk
Eighteen_wk
```

this is the SQL so far

```
 ALTER TABLE [Frontsheets].[dbo].[j38_spfit_op_activity_noc] 
    ADD
    APPOINTMENT_DATE nvarchar(11),
    APPOINTMENT_TIME datetime,
    Six_wk datetime,
    Eighteen_wk datetime
    go 
    update [Frontsheets].[dbo].[j38_spfit_op_activity_noc] set APPOINTMENT_DATE = APPT_DTTM, Six_wk = REF_DATE, Eighteen_wk = REF_DATE, APPOINTMENT_TIME = APPT_DTTM
    go
    UPDATE [Frontsheets].[dbo].[j38_spfit_op_activity_noc] SET Six_wk = DATEADD( "d" , 42, REF_DATE ), Eighteen_wk = DATEADD( "d" , 126, REF_DATE ) 
    Go


    Select REF_DATE = convert(nvarchar(10),REF_DATE, 103), 
    Six_wk = CONVERT(varchar(10), Six_wk, 103),
    Eigheen_wk = CONVERT(varchar(10), Eighteen_wk, 103)
    from [Frontsheets].[dbo].[j38_spfit_op_activity_noc]
```

Now I cant seem to save the converted data to my table?

Comment: You have a select, you need to use UPDATE.

Comment: What's the problem. Are you getting an error, or unexpected results

Comment: NEVER!!!! save a date in a table as text. It is the work of the application developer to format the date. The database should give the RAW data, and the lazy developer should FORMAT the data. It is bad practice, and a waste of space. And it is just wrong

Comment: Just change your select to an update and set the new data?